# Gravity forms Authorize.net add-on deducting regular amount instead of trail amount.

Tags: wordpress, authorize.net, add-on, recurring-billing, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using gravity form add-on of authorize.net to create monthly subscription in one of my WordPress site.
I have set the subscription amount to $50 and 1 month trial for $1 but when the transition is done the total amount charged $50 and authorize.net merchant interface shows me that trial period is set for on month with 1$ and amount is $50.
i am confused is there anything i am missing ?

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick test using the latest versions of both add-ons (GF v1.8.3 and Auth.net v1.5) and this worked as anticipated. Does your Auth.net account support Automated Recurring Billing (ARB)? If yes, and you're still having issues, [Gravity Forms support](http://www.gravityhelp.com/support) can help you get this figured out.

***Note to moderators**: I would have left this as a comment given that is isn't an actual answer to the issue but I do not have enough reputation to leave comments.*